# Based on this QQ-plot, does this looks approximately normal?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

based on the attached QQ-plot, can I say that the distribution is approximately normal? The results for Shapiro-Wilk test is p-value = 0.1334 but the sample size is small (only 12 as they are observations for each month) so I am not sure if its suitable to use the results from Shapiro test.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. As the line has a different slope by the line of `y = x`, it means that this distribution has a different skewness than the normal distribution.